# how to update a value from 'controller', in a 'directive'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write a 'dialog' directive for testing,but I don't know how to update the value from controller in a directive

```
app.controller('testController',function($scope){
    $scope.testValue = 'testing';
});

app.directive('testDirectvie',function(){
    return function(scope,element,attr){
         // this func will open the modal window,
         //  so how can I can the testValue from controller?Thx all
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element to which testDirective is added to is inside testController (e.g. `<div ng-controller="testController"><span test-directive=""></span></div>` ) then just access scope directly from the directive.

```
app.directive('testDirective',function(){
    return function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.testValue = "New value";
    };
});
```

An example - http://plnkr.co/edit/lN05YDr4bckrBRPiHyT7?p=preview

If testDirective is outside the scope of testController though, then you'll need to write a shared service which you can inject into both in order to share data.

An example of a service shared by both controller and directive - http://plnkr.co/edit/lN05YDr4bckrBRPiHyT7?p=preview

Comment: yes,my directive scope is out of testController,so how to write a shared service?you mean "broadcast" or else?thanks

Comment: and if I want input some paramters into the directive,how to do?

Comment: Well,broadcast is more for events, services are for sharing data. I updated my answer with an example of how services can work.

Comment: You can add them in HTML - test-directive="thisValue", and in the directive then read the value from attr.testDirective